# New Motherboard for SSD <Possible Crossfire>

Tags: graphics-cards, motherboard, ssd

> **Summary**: is it possible to get a cheap motherboard that supports an
>   AMD CPU, 2 Nvidia GPUs and AHCI for SSDs?
>
> **UPDATE**: Turns out the SSD works with the old setup (thanks,
>   @Journeyman). I now have the SSD along with the newer Nvidia on my
>   system. I have a spare Nvidia 560 Ti.

I built a PC 5 years ago with an AMD Phenom II X6 1100T CPU.

I bought an SSD recently but realized that it has problems due to lack of AHCI support on my motherboard.

I had an Nvidia 560Ti but recently upgraded to an Nvidia GTX750.

I'm planning to buy a new budget motherboard. I want one that supports SSD/AHCI, but since I have 2 Nvidia GPUs, I was wondering if it is worth getting a motherboard that supports multiple GPUs.

Comment: I've installed SSDs on motherboards as old as a core 2 duo from 2007. *anything* modern would do AHCI. or even NVMe over m.2 .  What sort of budget is budget? What parts do you intend to reuse?

Comment: I had an ASUS M4A87T motherboard. I was hoping to spend $50 - $80 on a new one, since PCpartpicker lists some in that price range ([ASRock 970 EXTREME4 w/ 2-way SLI], [ASRock 970 Pro3 R2.0 w/ (Quad) CrossfireX]). I'd like to use all the parts mentioned (CPU, 2 GPUs, SSD). I wanted to get my hands dirty with dual GPUs, but won't do it if it isn't worth it.

Comment: My BIOS only allows IDE mode for my SATA connected SSD, although I bought it in 2011. Strangely, this document does mention AHCI: http://www.manualslib.com/manual/431245/Asus-M4a87t.html?page=54. I will double check. I'd still like to upgrade if a dual-GPU makes a significant difference in in-game performance.

Comment: Update: @Journeyman: Turns out my SSD works with my old motherboard. Now I just need to know whether it's worth getting a new motherboard for SLI / Crossfire